# SwiftUI clean up ContentView

Tags: swiftui, state

I'm trying to simplify the ContentView within a project and I'm struggling to understand how to move `@State` based logic into its own file and have ContentView adapt to any changes. Currently I have dynamic views that display themselves based on `@Binding` actions which I'm passing the $binding down the view hierarchy to have buttons toggle the bool values.

Here's my current attempt. I'm not sure how in SwiftUI to change the view state of `SheetPresenter` from a nested view without passing the $binding all the way down the view stack. Ideally I'd like it to look like `ContentView.overlay(sheetPresenter($isOpen, $present)`.

Also, I'm learning SwiftUI so if this isn't the best approach please provide guidance.

```
class SheetPresenter: ObservableObject {

@Published var present: Present = .none
@State var isOpen: Bool = false

enum Present {
    case none, login, register
}

@ViewBuilder
func makeView(with presenter: Present) -> some View {
    switch presenter {
    case .none:
        EmptyView()
    case .login:
        BottomSheetView(isOpen: $isOpen, maxHeight: UIConfig.Utils.screenHeight * 0.75) {
            LoginScreen()
        }
    case .register:
        BottomSheetView(isOpen: $isOpen, maxHeight: UIConfig.Utils.screenHeight * 0.75) {
            RegisterScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: if you don't want to pass  $binding all the way down the view  you can create a StateObject variable in the top view and pass it with .environmentObject(). and access it from any view with  EnvironmentObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to pass  $binding all the way down the view  you can create a StateObject variable in the top view and pass it with .environmentObject(). and access it from any view with  EnvironmentObject

```
struct testApp: App {
        @StateObject var s1:  sViewModel = sViewModel()
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()               
                    .environmentObject(s1)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this kind of the same thing in that I'm passing an environmentObject down the path? - Also, Would stateObject allow me to alter it's inner working like the following `ContentView().Overlay(sViewModel.makeView())`

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it provided insight into the right approach to cleaning up the ContentView()

Comment: we don't use view model objects this would slow down SwiftUI we use @State and structs.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct this is not the best approach, however it is a common mistake. In SwiftUI we actually use `@State` for transient data owned by the view. This means using a value type like a struct, not classes. This is explained at 4:18 in [Data Essentials in SwiftUI from WWDC 2020](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020-10040/?time=258).

> EditorConfig can maintain invariants on its properties and be tested
> independently. And because EditorConfig is a value type, any change to
> a property of EditorConfig, like its progress, is visible as a change
> to EditorConfig itself.

```
struct EditorConfig {
    var isEditorPresented = false
    var note = ""
    var progress: Double = 0
    mutating func present(initialProgress: Double) {
        progress = initialProgress
        note = ""
        isEditorPresented = true
    }
}
struct BookView: View {
    @State private var editorConfig = EditorConfig()
    func presentEditor() { editorConfig.present(…) }
    var body: some View {
        …
        Button(action: presentEditor) { … }
        …
    }
}
```

Then you just use `$editorConfig.isEditorPresented` as the boolean binding in `.sheet` or `.overlay`.

Worth also taking a look at [sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) which makes it much simpler to show an item because no boolean is required it uses an optional `@State` which you can set to nil to dismiss.